# Trouble setting up field instance

Tags: entities

I have isolated my error to the `field_create_instance($instance)` line but can't make sense of what I'm doing wrong.

```
function my_module_quote_add_qid() {
$field = array(
    'field_name' => 'qid',
    'type' => 'text',
  );
  field_create_field($field);
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'qid',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'product',
    'label' => t('qid'),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'textfield',
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
}

my_module_quote_add_qid();
```

This is what my error looks like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: view modes in EntityDefaultRulesController->eventInfo() (line 51 of /var/www/seven/sites/all/modules/entity/entity.rules.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: schema_fields_sql in DrupalDefaultEntityController->buildQuery() (line 265 of /var/www/seven/includes/entity.inc).
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to SelectQuery::fields() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/seven/includes/entity.inc on line 284 and defined in SelectQuery->fields() (line 1300 of /var/www/seven/includes/database/select.inc).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

According to the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7), the only required properties are field_name, entity_type and bundle.  So I commented out:

```
'label' => t('qid'),
'widget' => array(
  'type' => 'textfield',
),
```

And now the field and instance install and uninstall properly.  I'm fairly sure `'textfield'` is an inappropriate widget type.